# jQuery: modify responseText in load() function

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

Is it possible to modify the responseText before adding to the element?

```
$('#target').load('script.php', params, function(response,status,xhr){
    response         = 'foo';  // doesn't work
    xhr.responseText = 'foo';  // doesn't work
    return 'foo';              // doesn't work        
})
```

I imagine the only way to get what I want is to use the `ajax` method and populate my target upon success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use [jQuery's `get` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get('script.php', params, function (responseText) {
    $('#target').html( responseText + 'foo' );
});
```

Comment: I selected this as answer; however, it should be noted that the `load` I code I used would be issuing a `POST`.  So `$.post()` would be more relative.  All-in-all thanks for the affirmation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <div>
    <img id="random-dog" src=""/>
  </div>
  <button>Get me a doggo</button>

  <script>
    $("button").click(function () {
      $("#random-dog").load("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random", function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
        if (statusTxt == "success")
          this.setAttribute("src", JSON.parse(responseTxt).message);
        console.log("External content loaded successfully!");
        if (statusTxt == "error")
          console.log("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Inside the callback function, if status text is success, process the response and set it to `this` src attribute. `this` means the selector element.

The API structure is :

```
{
    "message": "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/whippet/n02091134_10242.jpg",
    "status": "success"
}
```